# Make table inside table fit to the border and put the source into end of table

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]

I have a problem:

(1) I want the table inside table fit to the border

(2) I want put the source into end of table.

How to make it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont,lipsum}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{enumerate,enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
        \caption{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
        \label{papan} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{ABCDE}&\textbf{FGHIJKLMNOP}&\textbf{QRSTUV} \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{ABABABAB (Continuous)} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{TEXT}&\textbf{TEXT}&\textbf{TEXT} \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{r @{}}{\small\emph{to be continued}} \\*
        \multicolumn{3}{@{} l}{\small Source: ABCDE} \\
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %%%% table nody
        \textbf{12345}&909090&TEXT \\
        \hline
        \textbf{67890}&TEXT&TEXT\\
        \hline
        \textbf{13579}&TEXT &TEXT \\
        \hline
        \textbf{24680}&TEXT &TEXT \\
        \hline
        \textbf{14832}&TEXT&TEXT \\
        \hline
        TEXT&TEXT&TEXT \\
        \hline
        TEXT&TEXT&TEXT \\
        \hline
        TEXT&TEXT&
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0cm]
                \item A
                \item B
                \item C
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage} \\
        \hline
        A&B&C \\
        \hline
        & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l|l@{}}
            TEXT & TEXT\\ 
            \hline
            TEXT & TEXT\\
            \hline
            TEXT & TEXT \\
            \hline
            TEXT&TEXT \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l|l@{}}
        A&B\\
        \hline 
        TEXT&TEXT\\
        \hline
        TEXT&TEXT \\
        \hline
        TEXT&TEXT \\
        \end{tabular} \\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{TEXT}&\lipsum[1]&$1234$ \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered moving `\multicolumn{3}{@{} l}{\small Source: ABCDE} \\` to below `\endfoot`, so that is appears only in the last foot?

Comment: Oh, you're right. How about fit the table inside longtable to the cell border?